# adding soap header to asmx service on Windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, asmx

the web service (asmx) -which i have to use- want to a custom soap header. I tried to adding OperationContextScope Header just like that:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceStructureSoapClient client = new ServiceReference1.WebServiceStructureSoapClient();

client.getSectorsCompleted += asd_getSectorsCompleted;

AuthHeader serviceCredential = new AuthHeader() { Username = "xxxx", Password = "yyyyy" };

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
     MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("AuthHeader", "http://mobilecampaigns.org/", serviceCredential,true);
     OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(header);
     client.getSectorsAsync("test", "test", "i", "test");
}
```

In the server side, AutHeader is not null but username and Password are null.

Any idea?

Thanks